# Epsilon tensor VS. epsilon symbol

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I vaguely remember being told that there is a difference between saying "$\epsilon$ tensor" and "$\epsilon$ symbol". If I remember correctly, the epsilon *symbol* has something to do with the Levi-Civita $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and the epsilon *tensor*  is related to the volume form d$V$ with components $\sqrt{\text{det}g}\epsilon_{i,\ldots,j}$. So, my question is:

> What is the difference between the "$\epsilon$ tensor" and "$\epsilon$ symbol"?